# Any programs to generate css classes from your html?

Tags: css, html

Just curious does anyone know a program or script to generate a style sheet(with blank values obviously) from the structure of your html document? Basically just pull out the ID's and Classes you set in your html and make placeholder css so you don't have to plan it ahead of time or write it again ,remember D.R.Y. anyone?:)    Feel free to yell at me if you don't think this could help anyone else here :D  . I'm sure I could whip something up like that but if it's already out there I might as well stick to my rule of DRABEE(Don't repeat any body else either) . Thanks.

Comment: I’m not sure I see the sense of that. The whole purpose of CSS (*cascading*, remember?) is that not every ID and class is styled separately, but rather that they are styled depending on their position in the document and inherit certain styles, after a schema which *solely* depends on your style, not on your document structure. If you’re styling every ID and class separately, you’re doing it wrong.

Comment: Sounds like a good plan, I'm interested as well. I Agree with Konrad, but merely to get an impression of your document's structure it seems like a useful tool. It could perhaps also add classes that you have used in the HTML but have no definition in the CSS.

Comment: It wouldn't be able to handle `#id .class` cases or `.class .otherclass` or `.class, .similarclass`. So it might not be too useful indeed.. just saying, because i very often group classes with ids (*cascading and all*)..

Comment: if you are that lazy, why don't you use dreamweaver or something alike :D

Comment: @Konrad No I'm not doing everything separate. It's would be so I can avoid that very issue.

Comment: @Gaby , yeah that's kind of what I'm aiming for. I don't see any difficult parsing that kind of structure, I just don't want to do it if I someone else already did.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Did you check http://primercss.com/ ?
Seems to be doing exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: Primercss do it, but not make it right. It is very bad and useless to be honest.
But idea is really good and thankfully we have the http://lab.xms.pl/css-generator/. It is much better and actually works as expected =)

Answer (score 10):

CSS Frame Generator http://lab.xms.pl/css-generator/ works better than Primer.

Comment: This is the more advanced one out of all suggestions

Answer (score 2):

Little late to the party but these days, there is also BearCSS:

http://www.bearcss.com/

> #### Disclaimer
>
> This answer is primarily meant to add extra value to this thread and create an overview of CSS generators.

In my opinion, after trying all the mentioned tools in this thread, http://lab.xms.pl/css-generator/ is the best one.

Answer (score 1):

I found the best tools out there, after rigorous comparisons of the different available ones:

**If you want to generate CSS automatically from the markup online for free, then you need BeeCSS - CSS Generator:**

http://beecss.theextremewebdesigns.com/

**If you already have (messy) CSS & you would like to clean/minify it online for free, then you need BeeCSS - Cleaner Minifier**

http://beecss.theextremewebdesigns.com/css_clean_css_minify/