# Convert HTML to less/sass structure

Tags: html, css, sass, less

Quite often I create some html structure, and then I create less/sass styles for that. Usually every element in structure needs some styling and it requires me to 'rewrite' html structure to less/sass.

While rewriting there is only one rule - elements that appear multiple times in html are declared only once in less/sass.

Is there any tool that let me paste my HTML to it and that would generate corresponding less/sass structure that is ready for styling?

Example:

Such html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="elem"></div>
    <div class="elem">
        <div class="sub"></div>
        <div class="sub"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="elem">
        <img class="other-sub"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Would result in such less:

```
.container {

    .elem {

        .sub {

        }
        img.other-sub {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Any programs to generate css classes from your html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4920353/any-programs-to-generate-css-classes-from-your-html)

Comment: In my opinion it's not duplicate as .css is flat while less/sass can have tree structure thats quite similar to html.